# Reopen last opened activity after relaunching app

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to be able to reopen last opened activity after the app is closed, and after the phone is restarted.

I was referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441203/how-to-make-an-android-app-return-to-the-last-open-activity-when-relaunched) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621605/android-using-shared-preference-and-dispatcher-activity-to-get-back-to-the-last). In the 2nd link, I faced the same problem as OP in the comments of the marked answer but the solution did not work for me.

I am able to launch the app with the last open Activity, but clicking on a previous activity returns me a blank screen. After adding finish() to DispatcherActivity as 2nd link suggested, it closes the app with a log message:

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

I have searched for solutions to that error but they involved using 'connection.close()' or HTTP problems which were not relevant.

I have also tried alternatives like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652783/last-opened-activity) but they did not work either.

Regarding reopening the last opened screen after the phone is restarted, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1455063/7397164) stated that onSavedInstanceState would not work for a restarted phone.

This is the code for my AndroidManifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity.TakeoverMainActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.TakeoverNextActivity" />
    ...
    <activity android:name=".Activity.DispatcherActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is the code for my DispatcherActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dispatcher);

    Class<?> activityClass;

    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
        activityClass = Class.forName(
                prefs.getString(LAST_ACTIVITY, TakeoverMainActivity.class.getName()));
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        activityClass = TakeoverMainActivity.class;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityClass);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

This is the onPause methods of my other activities

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor activityEditor = prefs.edit();
    activityEditor.putString(LAST_ACTIVITY, getClass().getName());
    activityEditor.commit();

}
```

Any solutions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** SadiqMdAsif has solved my problem in the comments. My issue was that I used finish() on my 2nd Activity instead of starting a new intent.

Comment: do you mean open last activity when the user opens the app again?

Comment: "but clicking on a previous activity returns me a blank screen."  what does that mean?

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif An entirely white, blank activity. The 2nd link I mentioned in the question had the answerer who said that it was because DispatcherActivity was empty, so it was showing DispatcherActivity.

Comment: you mean `backbutton` press?  then `override` the `onBackPressed` method to switch to your desired `Activity`

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif not backbutton. Eg: I launch the app from **1st Activity**, click to **2nd Activity**, then close the app on the **2nd Activity**. I reopen the app, it loads on **2nd Activity**. If I click a button to go **3rd Activity**, it shows properly, but if I click a button to go **1st Activity** from the 2nd Activity, it's a **white activity**.

Comment: what's the code are your using to go to backActivity ? are you using new intent and then startActivty() ?

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif from 2nd Activity, I use finish(). My 1st Activity's onResume only contains sharedPreferences for retaining text in EditText

Comment: finish will close the app as after restart/relaunch as this is the first one in the Stack!   use intent to start previousActivity . This will do the work\

Comment: @SadiqMdAsif Ahhh I see. Thanks! I will try that. So I should not use finish() at all to navigate?

Comment: welcome. you can do it if you are in a flow and just finished doing any work on an Activity and just need to 'get back' not `go back` to the previous activity.

Comment: It works! Thanks! How do I reward you?